# Between function in R doesn't recognize incbounds argument

Tags: r

**I'm using the NYCflights13 data and I get an unused argument error for trying to find flights departing between 'a' and 'b'**

filter(flights, between(dep_time, 0, 600, incbounds = FALSE))

Error: Problem with `filter()` input `..1`.

ℹ Input `..1` is `between(dep_time, 0, 600, incbounds = FALSE)`.

x unused argument (incbounds = FALSE)

Comment: Check `?between` there is not `incbounds` argument. That explains the error.

Answer (score 1):

Unused argument means that incbounds parameter is not defined in `between()`. Here is the [doc](https://rdocumentation.org/packages/dplyr/versions/0.7.8/topics/between). You can write your own function for that.

```
between_new <- \(x, left, right, incbounds = TRUE) {
  if (incbounds) {
    x >= left & x <= right
  } else {
    x > left & x < right
  }
}

x <- filter(flights, between_new(dep_time, 0, 600, incbounds = FALSE))
summary(x$dep_time)
#    Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
#     1.0   538.0   554.0   480.9   556.0   559.0
```

Comment: thank you! Is there any dplyr or R function that lets you check between two values while excluding the bounds?

Comment: I am not aware of it. I guess you can easily exclude the bounds by removing one unit at the both ends: `filter(flights, between(dep_time, 0 + 1, 600 - 1))`